# PropertyGrid does not update selected object

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I want to implement a simple feature where user's can customize the `Font` of labels.

So I have `FontEditor` form with the following code:

```
public partial class FontEditor : Form
{
    public Font myFont;

    public FontEditor(Font myFont)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.myFont = myFont;

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = this.myFont;
    }

    private void FontEditor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

I use it on a chart control like this:

```
using (FontEditor fe = new FontEditor(chart1.Titles[0].Font))
{
    if (DialogResult.OK == fe.ShowDialog())
    {
        chart1.Titles[0].Font = fe.myFont;
    }
}
```

When the font editor loads, i can see the following:

[image]

If I changed the `Size` from `18` to `10` and close the window, the `SelectedObject` (which is my font object from chart title) does not appear to be changing/updating:

[image]

Doesn't editing the property grid values should update the `SelectedObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realise the silly mistake. The edits you do on `PropertyGrid` are actually in `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject`.

This is how I fixed it:

#### FontEditor.cs

```
public partial class FontEditor : Form
{
    public FontEditor(Font myFont)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myFont;
    }

    private void FontEditor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    public Font UpdatedFont
    {
        get { return propertyGrid1.SelectedObject as Font; }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
using (FontEditor fe = new FontEditor(chart1.Titles[0].Font))
{
    if (DialogResult.OK == fe.ShowDialog())
    {
        chart1.Titles[0].Font = fe.UpdatedFont;
    }
}
```

This now works.